# Xamarin forms chat App Editor Custom Render and Soft keyboard

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

[image]I am creating a chat app. I managed to get the Editor moving up and expanding. However, there's a space between the keyboard and Editor. How do I remove it?

I tried to remove it from the Xaml side and setting the margins an paddings does not seem to work

If there's another way to implement this, I'd love to her your suggestio

```
[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(ExtendedEditorControl), typeof(ExpandingEditoriOS))]
namespace Purplebunny.models.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class ExpandingEditoriOS:EditorRenderer
    {
        UILabel _placeholderLabel;
        double previousHeight = -1;
        int prevLines = 0;
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Editor> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                if (_placeholderLabel == null)
                {
                    CreatePlaceholder();
                }

            }

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                var customControl = (ExtendedEditorControl)e.NewElement;

                if (customControl.IsExpandable)
                    Control.ScrollEnabled = false;
                else
                    Control.ScrollEnabled = true;

                if (customControl.HasRoundedCorner)
                    Control.Layer.CornerRadius = 15;
                else
                    Control.Layer.CornerRadius = 0;

                Control.InputAccessoryView = new UIView(CGRect.Empty);
                Control.ReloadInputViews();

            }

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {

            }
        }



        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            var customControl = (ExtendedEditorControl)Element;

            if (e.PropertyName == Editor.TextProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                if (customControl.IsExpandable)
                {
                    CGSize size = Control.Text.StringSize(Control.Font, Control.Frame.Size, UILineBreakMode.WordWrap);

                    int numLines = (int)(size.Height / Control.Font.LineHeight);

                    if (prevLines > numLines)
                    {
                        customControl.HeightRequest = -1;

                    }
                    else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Control.Text))
                    {
                        customControl.HeightRequest = -1;
                    }

                    prevLines = numLines;
                }

                _placeholderLabel.Hidden = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Control.Text);

            }
            else if (ExtendedEditorControl.PlaceholderProperty.PropertyName == e.PropertyName)
            {
                _placeholderLabel.Text = customControl.Placeholder;
            }
            else if (ExtendedEditorControl.PlaceholderColorProperty.PropertyName == e.PropertyName)
            {
                _placeholderLabel.TextColor = customControl.PlaceholderColor.ToUIColor();
            }
            else if (ExtendedEditorControl.HasRoundedCornerProperty.PropertyName == e.PropertyName)
            {
                if (customControl.HasRoundedCorner)
                    Control.Layer.CornerRadius = 15;
                else
                    Control.Layer.CornerRadius = 0;
            }
            else if (ExtendedEditorControl.IsExpandableProperty.PropertyName == e.PropertyName)
            {
                if (customControl.IsExpandable)
                    Control.ScrollEnabled = false;
                else
                    Control.ScrollEnabled = true;

            }
            else if (ExtendedEditorControl.HeightProperty.PropertyName == e.PropertyName)
            {
                if (customControl.IsExpandable)
                {
                    CGSize size = Control.Text.StringSize(Control.Font, Control.Frame.Size, UILineBreakMode.WordWrap);

                    int numLines = (int)(size.Height / Control.Font.LineHeight);
                    if (numLines >= 5)
                    {
                        Control.ScrollEnabled = true;

                        customControl.HeightRequest = previousHeight;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Control.ScrollEnabled = false;
                        previousHeight = customControl.Height;

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void CreatePlaceholder()
        {
            var element = Element as ExtendedEditorControl;

            _placeholderLabel = new UILabel
            {
                Text = element?.Placeholder,
                TextColor = element.PlaceholderColor.ToUIColor(),
                BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear
            };

            var edgeInsets = Control.TextContainerInset;
            var lineFragmentPadding = Control.TextContainer.LineFragmentPadding;

            Control.AddSubview(_placeholderLabel);

            var vConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat(
                "V:|-" + edgeInsets.Top + "-[PlaceholderLabel]-" + edgeInsets.Bottom + "-|", 0, new NSDictionary(),
                NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys(
                    new NSObject[] { _placeholderLabel }, new NSObject[] { new NSString("PlaceholderLabel") })
            );

            var hConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat(
                "H:|-" + lineFragmentPadding + "-[PlaceholderLabel]-" + lineFragmentPadding + "-|",
                0, new NSDictionary(),
                NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys(
                    new NSObject[] { _placeholderLabel }, new NSObject[] { new NSString("PlaceholderLabel") })
            );

            _placeholderLabel.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

            Control.AddConstraints(hConstraints);
            Control.AddConstraints(vConstraints);
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using CoreGraphics;
using Foundation;[![enter image description here][1]][1]
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ChatInputBarView), typeof(ChatEntryRenderer))]
namespace Purplebunny.models.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class ChatEntryRenderer : ViewRenderer
    {
        NSObject _keyboardShowObserver;
        NSObject _keyboardHideObserver;
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                RegisterForKeyboardNotifications();
            }

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                UnregisterForKeyboardNotifications();
            }
        }

        void RegisterForKeyboardNotifications()
        {
            if (_keyboardShowObserver == null)
                _keyboardShowObserver = UIKeyboard.Notifications.ObserveWillShow(OnKeyboardShow);
            if (_keyboardHideObserver == null)
                _keyboardHideObserver = UIKeyboard.Notifications.ObserveWillHide(OnKeyboardHide);
        }

        void OnKeyboardShow(object sender, UIKeyboardEventArgs args)
        {

            NSValue result = (NSValue)args.Notification.UserInfo.ObjectForKey(new NSString(UIKeyboard.FrameEndUserInfoKey));
            CGSize keyboardSize = result.RectangleFValue.Size;
            if (Element != null)
            {
                Element.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, keyboardSize.Height);
            }
        }

        void OnKeyboardHide(object sender, UIKeyboardEventArgs args)
        {
            if (Element != null)
            {
                Element.Margin = new Thickness(0); 
            }

        }

        void UnregisterForKeyboardNotifications()
        {
            if (_keyboardShowObserver != null)
            {
                _keyboardShowObserver.Dispose();
                _keyboardShowObserver = null;
            }

            if (_keyboardHideObserver != null)
            {
                _keyboardHideObserver.Dispose();
                _keyboardHideObserver = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a ScrollView outside the layout, like this:

```
<ScrollView>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

            <local:MyEditor .../>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

[image]